# Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)

Tags: php, imap

When i trying to get messages from email via imap - i have this error:

> Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
>   OS: debian 7

Where is trouble?

PHP code:

```
<?php   
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'email@gmail.com';
$password = 'pass';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password, NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI')) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

/* begin output var */
$output = '';

/* put the newest emails on top */
rsort($emails);

/* for every email... */
foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

    /* output the email header information */
    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
}

echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: The message seems to be pretty clear and concise. The credentials you have supplied are not correct.

Comment: i put a valid email and password

Comment: clearly you didn't. are there any other vars other than user/pass that they need?

Comment: i think, that no

Comment: Is that the entire message?  Gmail has an array of security mechanisms to prevent accounts from being used from 'unusual places', and will block you for lots of reasons.  Usually there's an error with a link, and you can generate an App Specific Password, or implement OAuth.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using G Suite, you have to contact your G Suite administrator to enable not secure access for users apps in Google Admin panel, URL like `https://admin.google.com/{YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME}/AdminHome?hl=en#ServiceSettings/notab=1&service=securitysetting&subtab=lesssecureappsaccess`

or go this way (for G Suite admin)

1. https://admin.google.com
2. Security settings
3. Basic settings (first link)
4. Less secure apps -> Go to settings for less secure apps
5. Enforce access to less secure apps for all users (Not Recommended)
6. Save
7. PROFIT (can take effect in 1-2 mins, wait for some time please)

Comment: turn on the Less secure apps setting for both account. i got this same problem. first i enabled  less secure apps from administrator account. then i enabled for the user's email. finaly that worked

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using G Suite, check below url and turn on "less secure apps"
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Gmail IMAP settings
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'your_email@gmail.com';
$password = 'your_password';

// Connect to the IMAP server
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

// Get the list of email messages
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');

if ($emails) {
    foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
        // Fetch email structure and headers
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
        $header = imap_fetchheader($inbox, $email_number);

        echo "Subject: " . $overview[0]->subject . "<br>";
        echo "From: " . $overview[0]->from . "<br>";
        echo "Date: " . $overview[0]->date . "<br>";
        echo "Message ID: " . $overview[0]->message_id . "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";

        // Fetch email body
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1.1); // 1.1 represents plain text part
        echo "Message: " . $message . "<hr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No emails found.";
}

// Close the connection
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

Replace 'your_email@gmail.com' and 'your_password' with your actual Gmail email and password. Keep in mind that storing passwords in plaintext within your code is not secure. It's recommended to use a more secure method to manage credentials, such as environment variables or a configuration file with restricted access.

Also, note that if you're using two-factor authentication for your Gmail account, you might need to generate an "App Password" and use that instead of your actual account password.

Lastly, be aware that the above code only fetches the plain text part of the email body. If you want to handle HTML content and attachments, you'll need to adjust the code accordingly.

Please exercise caution while handling email credentials and personal data in your code. Always follow best practices for security.