# How to fix this issue? Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}. [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials

Tags: laravel, imap, gmail-imap

I am using laravel-IMAP to integrate Gmail with my laravel project and package I follow is **Webklex/laravel-imap**.
Issue is when i test my code the error poped-up, I followed to many links to figure-out my issue, one solution i find is to enable **IMAP access: Enable IMAP**, but it is not a solution for all the users, I want to fetch the emails of that user's those who will use this application with doing enable imap access. Is there any other solution to overcome this problem?

> Controller

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $oClient = new Client([
            'host'          => 'imap.gmail.com',
            'port'          => 993,
            'encryption'    => 'ssl',
            'validate_cert' => true,
            'username'      => '**********',
            'password'      => '**********',
            'protocol'      => 'imap'
        ]);
        /* Alternative by using the Facade
        $oClient = Webklex\IMAP\Facades\Client::account('default');
        */

        //Connect to the IMAP Server
        $oClient->connect();

        //Get all Mailboxes
        /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Support\FolderCollection $aFolder */
        $aFolder = $oClient->getFolders();

        //Loop through every Mailbox
        /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Folder $oFolder */
        foreach($aFolder as $oFolder){

            //Get all Messages of the current Mailbox $oFolder
            /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Support\MessageCollection $aMessage */
            $aMessage = $oFolder->messages()->all()->get();

            /** @var \Webklex\IMAP\Message $oMessage */

            foreach($aMessage as $oMessage){
                echo $oMessage->getSubject().'<br />';
                echo 'Attachments: '.$oMessage->getAttachments()->count().'<br />';
                echo $oMessage->getHTMLBody(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326173/can-not-authenticate-to-imap-server-authenticationfailed-invalid-credentials seems to address this. any help there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not authenticate to IMAP server: \[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED\] Invalid credentials (Failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326173/can-not-authenticate-to-imap-server-authenticationfailed-invalid-credentials)

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper Provided link is not the solution..

Comment: @arnt Provided link is not the solution..

Comment: In that case, please provide a protocol log with the imap commands and responses.

Comment: Have you tried using Google's authorization to make this IMAP request? [Check the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp) for information about authorizing IMAP access in Gmail for developers and see if [this example](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/blob/master/php/oauth2.php) of the [PHP implementation](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode) helps you solve your doubts. **Please let me know if that worked.** Thanks !